# How to remove web address from one heroku "location" and use it in another?

Tags: heroku

I apologize for not understanding the terminology here:

I launched a rails app on heroku and eventually borked the db.  I deleted my master git branch and created a new one.  When I pushed it out to heroku it went to a different "location."

Location 1: stormy-anchorage...
Location 2: vast-brushlands...

I want to add the web address to vast-brushlands but apparently I can't because I already have it assigned to stormy-anchorage.  Is there a way to "put" myself in stormy-anchorage to delete the web address and then move back to brushlands to add it there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you want to remove one Heroku git remote and add another.

If you want to blow away the old app, its addons, and the git remote, you can do this:

```
$ heroku destroy --app stormy-anchorage
```

If you just want to remove the git remote, but leave the app itself in place, do this:

```
$ git remote rm heroku
```

Once you do either one of the above, you'll need to associate your new app with the `heroku` git remote, like this:

```
$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:vast-brushlands.git
```